# Load 'summarize' Table in as Data Set in Stata

Tags: stata

In Stata, when one does the following command:

```
tabulate Variable1, summarize(Variable2)
```

It presents the table in the results viewer.

Is there a way/command that one can do to load this new table of data in as a data set so that one could order the list by one of the statistical variables such as Mean, Std. Freq.?

Thanks.

Comment: `help collapse` to find out about such reductions.

Comment: @NickCox Would you be able to explain what you mean about "reductions"? Thanks.

Comment: Data reduction is primarily reducing it to a smaller dataset. A standard term in  science for two centuries, as I understand it. Wikipedia says more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_reduction

Answer (score 0):

here it is brother

```
collapse (sum) sum = Variable1 (mean) mean = Variable1 (count) count = Variable1, by(Variable2) fast
```

Comment: While I sympathise with your frustration at the downvote, which I reversed, swearing at the world won't get it explained.